# Pandas difference of successive elements

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Assume I have a data frame like so

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data=np.random.random(10,10))
```

I need to create a dataframe(call it diff) such that for every i in diff meets the following criteria

```
diff[i] = df[i]-df[i-1]
```

I can do this iteratively but that doesn't scale well. How would you do this in pandas with super fast speed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC use [`DataFrame.diff`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.diff.html):

```
np.random.seed(2022)

df = pd.DataFrame(data=np.random.random((3,3)))
print(df)
          0         1         2
0  0.009359  0.499058  0.113384
1  0.049974  0.685408  0.486988
2  0.897657  0.647452  0.896963

df1 = df.diff(-1)
print(df1)
          0         1         2
0 -0.040615 -0.186350 -0.373604
1 -0.847683  0.037956 -0.409975
2       NaN       NaN       NaN


df2 = df.diff()
print(df2)
          0         1         2
0       NaN       NaN       NaN
1  0.040615  0.186350  0.373604
2  0.847683 -0.037956  0.409975
```

Numpy alternatives for improve performance with [`numpy.diff`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.diff.html) and DataFrame constructor:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.diff(-df, axis=0, append=np.nan), 
                   index=df.index, columns=df.columns)
print(df1)
          0         1         2
0 -0.040615 -0.186350 -0.373604
1 -0.847683  0.037956 -0.409975
2       NaN       NaN       NaN

df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.diff(df, axis=0, prepend=np.nan), 
                   index=df.index, columns=df.columns)
print(df2)
          0         1         2
0       NaN       NaN       NaN
1  0.040615  0.186350  0.373604
2  0.847683 -0.037956  0.409975
```

**Performance**:

```
np.random.seed(2022)

df = pd.DataFrame(data=np.random.random((3000,3000)))


In [75]: %timeit df.diff()
142 ms ± 3.34 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

In [76]: %timeit pd.DataFrame(np.diff(df, axis=0, prepend=np.nan), index=df.index, columns=df.columns)
77.1 ms ± 469 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```